# What is the exact criteria for a type to be Storable?

Tags: haskell, containers, gadt, data-kinds

I implemented a data type for symmetric groups (and cyclic groups) long time ago:

```
newtype Cyclic (n :: Nat) = Cyclic {cIndex :: Integer}

data Symmetric (n :: Nat) where
    S1 :: Symmetric 1
    (:.) :: Cyclic n -> Symmetric (n-1) -> Symmetric n
```

This is an inhomogeneous container, <s>but I'm not sure whether this is an array or a list.</s> As the comments clarify, this is not an issue.

<s>If this is an array,</s> it would be possible to implement `instance Storable (Symmetric n)`. Why exactly is it possible to do so?

Comment: It's a list, but that's kind of orthogonal to being able to write a `Storable` instance.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'd like to see why. (As an answer)

Comment: @leftaroundabout To be specific, I don't know how Haskell knows this is "orthogonal".

Comment: @leftaroundabout Also, if this is a list, wouldn't that mean the elements will stored in noncontinuous addresses (just like C++'s `std::list`)?

Comment: @DannyuNDos The distinction between ‘lists’ and ‘arrays’ is not as important in Haskell as it is in C++, since the location in which data is stored is of importance in C (and C++) but not in Haskell. In Haskell, ‘true’ arrays (stored continuously) are very rare; they can be found in the `array` and `vector` libraries, but are not generally used unless performance becomes important. The normal Haskell type `[]` is a linked list; most other containers are implemented internally as some form of tree. In this case, you are implementing `Symmetric` as a linked list.

Comment: @DannyuNDos And as for the ‘orthogonal’ comment, leftaroundabout is simply saying that whether or not it is a list is of no relevance to the issue of writing a `Storable` instance.

Comment: @bradrn It's confusing. I thought `[]` isn't `Storable` because it has unbounded size.

Comment: @DannyuNDos I don’t know much about `Storable`, but some cursory research seems to confirm what you say. In particular, a `Storable` type seems to require a _fixed_ size, so e.g. `Int8`, `Int16`, … are `Storable`, but `Integer` isn’t.

Comment: @bradrn It's funny because in proper, idiomatic C++, the difference between lists and arrays isn't any more important than it is in Haskell.  It's just that everybody tries to program C++ like it's C :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Storable` is meant to evoke the idea of C `struct`s. As a `struct`, any type that is `Storable` is bounded in size. `Storable (Symmetric n)` is possible because `Symmetric n` is, in fact, bounded-size. (Assuming that `Cyclic n`s are equivalent modulo `n`,) It has `n!` values, which is finite, and so you don't need unbounded space. More specifically, just `log2(n!)` bits will suffice. Note that I'm talking about `Symmetric n` *for some specific `n`*. For different `Nat`s `n`, `m`, etc. `Symmetric n`, `Symmetric m`, etc. are different types, and so they may therefore have different sizes. For a *single* `n :: Nat`, `Symmetric n` has a fixed size.

The real issue is picking an encoding. For ease of implementation, you could use a recursive encoding, where a `Storable n` consists of `ceil(log2(n) / 8)` bytes to hold the first number followed by a `Storable (n - 1)`. Then, `Symmetric 1` will be 0 bytes, `Symmetric 2` will be 1 byte (with only one bit of it used), `Symmetric 3` will be 2 bytes, ..., `Symmetric 256` will be 255 bytes, `Symmetric 257` will be 257 bytes (because the first number has 257 choices and therefore needs two bytes). This is certainly not efficient, but you can clearly see that there's a well-defined size for every `Symmetric n`. If you want to get down to the bound of `log2(n!)` bits (really, `ceil(log2(n!)/8)` bytes), you'd have to do some ~~funky math~~ (which I'm not familar with), but you can do it.

You need singletons to make this work; it's possible to write

```
instance KnownNat n => Storable (Symmetric n)
```

but not

```
instance Storable (Symmetric n)
```

Types are erased, so the second `instance` is not told what `n` is and thus can't read anything (or implement `sizeof`, etc.). It *can* write, because `Symmetric` is a GADT and thus contains information about what `n` is.

---

Side note: should not `Symmetric 0` be nonempty?

```
data Symmetric (n :: Nat) where
    S0 :: Symmetric 0
    (:.) :: Cyclic n -> Symmetric (n - 1) -> Symmetric n
```

`Symmetric 0` is the set of bijections from the empty set to itself, and there's just one function (the empty set) in that set.

Comment: Is it irrelevent that `Cyclic n` has `Integer`, an unbounded size?

Comment: A `Cyclic n` represents a number from `0` to `n-1`. Logically, that's a finite number of values, therefore there is a finite-sized encoding. The fact that you've decided to *implement* it as an `Integer` is irrelevant. You could e.g. say `data Cyclic n where CZ :: Cyclic 1; CS :: Cyclic n -> Cyclic (S n)` and build the same logic on top of it. Depending on how you're dealing with it, e.g. a `Cyclic 10 :: Cyclic 5` is either just invalid, or is considered equal to `Cyclic 0`. Either way, you don't care about anything outside the range `0` to `n-1`.